# Wordpress transfer to new ftp. Help, Home link doesn't work?

Tags: wordpress, ftp, hyperlink, transfer

Hi I've transfered my wordpress site to a new ftp server, but my home link doesn't work properly. When I click on it, it goes to http://123.456.78.8/mydomain.com and I get a page not found message. I've discovered it needs a / at the end to work.

Does anyone know a way to fix this before I put it on my live site?
Could it be a database or config file issue?

Thanks for all your help

Regards

Judi

P.S Could it be the permalink structure? Will it work when change my domain to http://mydomain.com?

Comment: Do the other links work?

Answer (score 0):

You probably set your home URL to mydomain.com. It should be http://mydomain.com